# How to use firebug to see live JS calls

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm trying to debug or see what functions are being called when I do certain actions on a website.

How can I use firebug to show me only the functions that are being called currently?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for [Profiler](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Profiler). You may also use it from the code by calling [`console.profile()`](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.profile.28.5Btitle.5D.29) and [`console.profileEnd()`](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.profileEnd.28.29).

BTW, `console.profile` and `console.profileEnd` exists also in recent versions of Webkit based browsers like Chrome/Chromium and Safari...

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps to go ahead
1.Click on script tab in firebug panel
2.A panel will open on the right which has tabs as watch , stack and  breakpoint
3.Click on breakpoint and add a breakpoint to a specific function.
4.Debug through and you will see the functions being called.
Hope this helps.